# How do I get my arrow text to stay in the right place on fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am new here and I am looking for the answer to something that is bugging me so much. I am working on a website for a client and it uses fullpage.js..... you can see the website at http://begemini.co.uk/workshop/loweclothing/index.html

The problem is I am having issues with the text next to the arrows. I can't get the right text to stay on "slide1" I have tried using "position:fixed" but it stays in the right place but it is on every slide and I need different text on each slide....

The html code is:

```
    <body>
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1"><img src="imgs/Lowe-Clothing-logo.png" width="30%">
            <div id="left-text">Business Opportunities</div><!--left-text-->
  <div id="right-text">Introduction</div><!--right-text--></div><!--Slide1-->
    <div class="slide" id="slide2"><h1>Totally customizable</h1></div><!--Slide2-->
</div>


</body>
```

And the css is:

```
#left-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60px;
    margin-top:-9px;
    font-size: 1.1em;   
    font-family: arial,helvetica;
    color: #fff;
 }

 #right-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 60px;
    margin-top:-9px;
    font-size: 1.1em;   
    font-family: arial,helvetica;
    color: #fff;
    z-index:100;
 }
```

So basically I am trying to place the text to the arrows but to transition with the rest of the content. And I want different text next to the arrows on each page. You can download the whole site [here](http://begemini.co.uk/workshop/loweclothing/backup.zip) to have a look at the whole code.

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Did you tried relative instead of fixed?

Comment: I did and that didn't work either. It kept them on the same slide but they went in completely the wrong place and didn't work properly when the screen was resized :/

Comment: I have uploaded the site with position:relative on

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use only one kind of css unit, i.e. only pixels or only em.

Try this and subsequently use relative or absolute and try if it works.

Comment: I only use em for font size, everything is arranged with px and absolute puts the right text on the other slide...

Comment: does the text need to be in a container or does the whole slide need a "wrap"?

Comment: right I have managed to get them to stay in the right place when the screen is maximized and at normal zoom but they move about when I change the screen size or zoom in.... the new site is at http://begemini.co.uk/workshop/loweclothing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The logic appears to be wrong.

try position:relative instead of fixed or absolute
and set top, left, and right to auto or x%.

The key should be working with the position, top, left, and right.

Comment: I tried relative but I cant seem to get them in the right place and they don't stay in the right place when I resize the screen

Answer (score 0):

What you should do in order to change the text for each slide is to use the callbacks the plugin offers. 
In this case you would need to use the callback [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex)

That way you will be able to decide with jQuery which text you want to add for each slide with something like:

```
$('textLeft').text('demo');
$('textRight').text('demo');
```

In order to position the text correctly, you can do it with absoluted positioned as the sections have `position:relative`.